# Fallout 4 Sturges Glitch (Stuck in Concord with Power Armor)

Tags: fallout-4

Sturges is currently roaming around Concord in my X0-1 power armor, killing anything in sight. Besides that, he just kind of stands there and when I attempt to talk to him, the only dialogue I get in return is, "What's up!?"

Although Sturges seems to be enjoying his newfound freedom, I'd really like to get back my set of X0-1 Power Armor and whatever weapon he seems to have stolen. I am very late in game so I don't understand why this happened! While I was in Far Harbor Sanctuary I got attacked, but I wouldn't think he'd stray that far. Please help!

Comment: This gave me a good laugh. All I could imagine was a guy walking around in epic power armour, shooting at raiders and such, and every time he kills something he goes "What's up?"

Comment: Seems pretty clear to me. "Sturges is in power armor and won't get out. How do I get him out?" Voted to reopen.

Comment: I also looked around and couldn't find a duplicate. There's a question about getting NPCs out of power armor, but the question and the answer are all oriented towards enemies, not settlers. There's a question about getting Carla out of power armor, which is pretty close, but the top-voted solution there is to wait until she goes to Bunker Hill, which doesn't work for Sturges. The other answers are pretty much the same as the other NPC one.

Comment: It wouldn't be too hard to grab one of the other x-01 sets and rebuild if all else fails.

Comment: `player.placeatme 00170446` (spawns a full suit of X-01 PA w/o a core) I couldn't get my Sturges to get in a suit, so I cannot confirm that setting him as non-essential, killing him, and then looting him as a viable option, but I think it's worth a try.

Answer (score 4):

You can't order non-companion NPCs to leave Power Armor, sadly. At least without mods.

What you can do is pickpocket the Fusion Core from their inventory, and if that doesn't work shoot the Fusion Core out of the back of the Armor. When it blows up the NPC is forced to exit the Armor.

If you don't have a Fusion Core in the armor and Sturges is still using it, then you're SoL. If you're on PC I'd suggest looking up a mod that allows you to tell settlers to leave Power Armor or console commands to add the pieces of Power Armor you've lost to your inventory.

Comment: Consoles also have mods now. However, PC mods have to be ported to console, so the existence of a mod on PC doesn't necessarily imply that same mod exists on console.